# Apple pulled Mojave 10.14.0 -- Where can i get it? -- 10.14.4,,,10.14.6 etc., are still available from Apple

Tags: mojave, upgrade

I cannot upgrade to MOJAVE.  After spending a lot of time searching through Apple's download site, I contacted Apple support and they told me that I cannot download Mojave 10.14.0.  That version has been removed from their download files.  Other later versions are still available.  However, I CANNOT INSTALL 10.14.4 OR 10.14.6 without first installing 10.14.0.  Are there any non Apple sites that make that 10.14.0 download available?????

Comment: Why do you think you need 10.14.0?  Did Apple tell you that?  Normally you upgrade directly to the latest version.

Comment: I cannot upgrade to Catalina.  I use Aperture for my photo management and Aperture is cannot run on Catalina.  Eventually I will go to a different photo management program, but it's a lot of work to change.  I want to be on the most up to date operating system if I can.

Comment: Have you gone to this page?   https://support.apple.com/macos/mojave

Comment: @DenZ I think you're getting confused by the distinction between an *updater* package (available from [support.apple.com/downloads](https://support.apple.com/downloads)), which can only update minor versions (e.g. 10.14.0 -> 10.14.6); and an *installer*, which can do both clean installs and major version upgrades (e.g. 10.13.6 -> 10.14.6). You need an installer. The 10.14.6 installer is what you want, and it's available from a link [here](https://support.apple.com/macos/mojave) (this is one of the links Minteck gave).

Answer (score -1):

If you can't install macOS Mojave, your Mac may not be compatible.

First check the requirements on [Apple Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP777?locale=en_US). Then, you can manually download the installer through [Apple Official Support](https://support.apple.com/macos/mojave) or the Mac App Store.

If you still can't update to macOS Mojave, you may download the installer from an external source, like I did when I needed to update from Snow Leopard (10.8) to El Capitan (10.11).

Comment: OP was presumably trying to download an updater, delta or combo, which requires a previous major version first. El Capitan is available from official sources for intermediate upgrades from 10.6 or later.

Comment: I understand that the OP want to update to Mojave 10.14.4 or 10.14.6 but it requires installing 10.14.0 and he can't because he couldn't find a download link.

Comment: There is no link for 10.14.0.  I did confirm this via a telephone call to Apple Tech. Support.  They said to fill out a feed back complaint and that they do read those complaints and might make it available again.  The reason I want Mojave is that I'm trying to upgrade my photo editing code and photo management code.  Aperture will not run on Catalina.  I wanted download Pixelmator Pro for photo editing, but it requires Mojave.   Is there a non-apple source where I can download Mojave 10.14.0??

Comment: The final solution is to search on Internet to download the offline macOS Mojave 10.14.0 installer and start it manually. I did that for El Capitan and that worked... If that still doesn't work, you may either download Catalina if the Mac is compatible, or I don't know...

Comment: @DenZ Is there any reason you're looking for 10.14.0 instead of an installer (*not* updater) for 10.14.6? A 10.14.6 installer is essentially equivalent to a 10.14.0 installer plus the 10.14.6 update, but as a single unit.